# Converting .geotiff to .tiff

Tags: raster, geotiff-tiff, file-formats, raster-conversion

How do I convert .geotiff files to .tiff files (ordinary plain images)?

Basically, I have cropped the image to a rectangle of interest and
knowing its left-lower location and having chosen the pixel size,
I could combine several data sources as ordinary .tiffs.

Any working method goes. We will employ usual image processing tools, and the location information is useless at that phase.

This is what I got when I tried to read GeoTiff in GIMP 2.8.4:

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use gdal: (you can change PNG to JPG or TIFF too)

```
    for %i in (*.tif) do gdal_translate -of PNG -scale -co worldfile=no %i %~cnvt.png
```

Answer (score 5):

You probably don't need to convert a GeoTiff to a Tiff.

As a GeoTiff your image will not only be readable by any GIS package but probably can also be read by any image manipulation package too (e.g. Photoshop, GIMP etc) baring some exceptions.  Image editing packages simply ignore the bits in the Tiff header that make it a GeoTiff - either that or they give you a warning dialog box to say something about unrecognized tags in the header, but you can just ignore that.  When you save the image out of (say) PhotoShop, it kills the GeoTiff headers if you save it as a new file after processing (which is probably a good idea if you manually manipulate your image in this way).  I don't recommend editing raster data in Photoshop but if you want to, you can without doing anything to the Geotiff first.