# Dealing with GeoTIFF-file in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, geotiff-tiff, spatial-analyst, export

I'm doing data-analysis on satellite data and my source data is in GeoTIFF-file format. What I would like to do with the data is:

```
1) Open the raster data in ArcMap etc.  
2) Change the coordinate system from WGS84 --> ETRS-TM35FIN 
3) Extract an area from the original data specified by ETRS-TM35FIN coordinates 
4) Save the extracted area as plain .tif-file so that I can do data-analysis on it in Matlab
```

Can someone give the steps I need to do, in order to achieve my goals?

I have no experience in ArcGIS software and the terminology etc. is very new to me, but I don't want to start reading a 500 page book just to get my data into a format so that I can analyze it in Matlab.

The following picture will summarize my question:

[image]

---

I'm able now to extract specific area from the GeoTiff, but I can't save it as a plain .tiff-file:

[image]

Comment: Do you have access to the Spatial Analyst extension? It will be required for extracting by cooridnates.

Comment: Hi @Devdatta Tengshe Yes, I do =) But I don't know how to use it. The whole program is new to me :S

Comment: Matlab can also read and write geotiff-files (R2011 and later)

Comment: +1 @Martin Thank you for your help! But don't I need the Mapping toolbox for that? Which I don't have :/

Comment: @jjepsuomi Yes, I'm afraid that you do need the Mapping toolbox.

Comment: Damn...x) Thanx for the help anyway =)

Comment: Also, try using only one "f", like .tif

Comment: +1 But isn't that again a GeoTiff? I want a plain tiff-file with no metadata so that Matlab can read it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll suggest that you can do this using [Geoprocessing](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/A_quick_tour_of_geoprocessing/002s00000002000000/) . This will be the way with the least amount of interaction with ArcGIS. This needs to be just a two stage process.

1. Firstly, you will need to run the [Project Raster](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000007m000000) tool. You can export the raster to ETRS-TM35FIN coordinate system
2. Then you can extract the required area, by using the [Extract by Polygon (Spatial Analyst)](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Extract_by_Polygon/009z0000002q000000/)  tool.  in the out raster, if you provide the name with .tif, it will be exported as a Tiff File

Comment: I have a problem with exporting the file as a plain .tif-file

Comment: I will post print screen here. The Extract by Polygon complains that the file format isn't allowed even though I gave it the file extension .tiff

Comment: @jjepsuomi: Please try with the extension`.tif` Single f, not double f

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I tried that and it worked. But isn't that again a GeoTiff? Not plain TIFF, because I can't view the extracted file in Windows Photo Viewer. Windows Photo Viewer says that the file format is not recognized, which implies to me that it is a GeoTiff ? =)

Comment: +1 Okay Thank you. I couldn't earlier convert it succesfully from GeoTiff to Tiff, but I will try to do it again. Thanx for your effort! =)

Comment: @jjepsuomi: On further reading, I understand it might not always work. GeoTiff can contain data in as high as 32 bit data. Tiff on the other hand can contain only bytes.

Comment: Yes :( I tried to open the GeoTiff in GIMP 2.8.4, but it didn't work out also. It complained about what you just mentioned...that it can't handle images with 32-bit samples x( I was so close :D You can see GIMP's error here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/61635/how-to-convert-geotiff-tiff . Would you have any other ideas how to do get it as plain .tiff? That's all there's left to do, then I would celebrate victory x)

Comment: One way I have found out, is that you can add the geotiff to ArcMap, and then export the entire map to Tiff. http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00sm00000004000000 This will ofcourse lead to loss of resolution ( both from 32 bit to 8 bit, as well as less number of pixels)

Comment: Thank you @Devdatta Tengshe you have been extremely helpful. I will try that. I'm a bit worried though about the loss of information...will have to see what to do =)